# Invoke callback in Moq

Tags: unit-testing, c#-3.0, moq, mstest

I have a method that performs an asynchronous service call.  I call this class by passing in the callback.

```
public void GetRights(EventHandler<GetRightsCompletedEventArgs> callback)
{
    ServiceClient client = new ServiceClient();
    client.GetRightsCompleted += new EventHandler<GetRightsCompletedEventArgs>(callback);
    client.GetRightsAsync();
}

GetRights(GetRightsCallback);
```

I'm creating tests with MSTest, and I've mocked the containing class (IGetRightsProxy) in Moq.  How can I invoke the callback when this method is called in the test?

```
GetRightsForCurrentUserCompletedEventArgs results = 
    new GetRightsCompletedEventArgs(
    new object[] { new ObservableCollection<Right>()}, null, false, null);
Mock<IGetRightsProxy> MockIGetRightsProxy = new Mock<GetRightsProxy>();
```

Comment: It's not very clear what it is you are trying to accomplish. If I understand the code correctly, the ServiceClient will invoke the callback, so it's not something you should be doing from your test via Moq.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way of doing what I want is to extend the class like this:

```
class MockGetRightsProxy : IGetRightsProxy
{
    public void GetRights(EventHandler<GetRightsCompletedEventArgs> callback)
    {
        // Create some args here
        GetRightsCompletedEventArgs args = new GetRightsCompletedEventArgs(
            new object[] { new ObservableCollection<Right>() }, null, false, null);

        callback(null, args);
    }

}
```

I was looking for ways to invoke the callback in Moq, but this works, too.

Answer (score 0):

You want to be looking at Moq's `Callback()` extension on your mock;

```
Mock<IGetRightsProxy> mock = new Mock<IGetRightsProxy>();
mock.Setup(x => x.GetRights(It.IsAny<EventHandler<GetRightsCompletedEventArgs>>())
  .Callback<EventHandler<GetRightsCompletedEventArgs>>(
    callback => callback(mock.Object, new GetRightsCompletedEventArgs())
  );
```

When the code under test calls `GetRights()` on the `IGetRightsProxy` mock the actual `EventHandler<GetRightsCompletedEventArgs>` it passes in will subsequently be passed into Moq's `Callback()` method.

Note: Type inference will work on the generic applied to `Callback()` but I find in these cases it is a bit more readable to explicitly define the type being passed into the method.